# React-native Why Menu is not rendering

Tags: react-hooks, react-native

i have a menu for each item of a flatlist, however when ever i press on the button to show the menu nothing happens when i log the  visible state of the menu i see that it is being set to true but it is not rendering.

this is a component to render each item with a menu

```js
 const RenderItem =(props)=>{
    return(
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{}}>
      <View  style={styles.flatitem}>
          <Icon style={styles.pdf} name="file-pdf-o" color="#666"/>
          <Text style={styles.itemtext}>{props.title}</Text>
          <Menu 
          visible={visible}
          {...console.log(visible)}
          anchor={<Button onPress={openMenu} >
             show
          </Button>}
          onDismiss={closeMenu} >
          <Menu.Item icon="pencil-box-outline" onPress={() =>{}} title="Rename" />
          <Menu.Item icon="label-outline" onPress={() => {}} title="Label" />
          <Menu.Item icon="delete-outline" onPress={() => {}} title="Delete" />  
         </Menu>  
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity> )}
```

this is the flatlist:

```js
  <FlatList style={styles.flatstyle}
              keyExtractor={(item)=>item['id']}
              data={DATA}
              renderItem={({item})=>(<RenderItem title={item.title }/>)}
              />
```

and these are the open and close functions

```js
 const [visible,setVisible]=useState(false)
 
  const openMenu = () => {
    setVisible(true)
     }
const closeMenu = () => setVisible(false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i am right, it is actually not a problem. FlatList is a pure component and will only re-render if the data prop changes i.e, the data passed to the flatlist changes.

As `visible` is not in data, so it doesnot re-render.

To make it re-render and show the menu, you need to use `extraData` prop of the flatlist, which will take some other data. If that other data changes, that will also cause a re-render and that other data in your case is the `visible` variable.

More details [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#extradata)

Comment: You can mark my answer as accepted if it helped. Thanks